# how i bake my node setup in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, baking

as you can see in the screenshots i want to bake the same result of the viewport as new baked texture,and the same goes for the other nodes beside it, but i dont see anyway to do it, i tried with baking with diffuse and it bakes a black or white texture with shadows from the hdri lighting, also obviously i want my texture shadeless, which means none hdri lighting baked on it. and BTW how can i add a clearcoat as a texture which means more glossiness in the surface but in the red painted part only (tho i have to invert the textures cuz i want the red look like car paint and the metal less glossy than it is). [image]

the texture that i want to bake just like appears rendered [image] full node preview [image]

EDIT: i finally could bake this i just had to bake it with a diffuse shader which means i had to put my node setup in the color input of the diffuse node and then add other separate image with a new image created and just keep it selected and without plugging it in another node and then go to the bake settings, select diffuse, and uncheck direct and indirect button and then bake and wait until the bake was done.

Comment: Principled BSDF has a clearcoat slider

Comment: @WhatAMesh this pbr node group is from remington graphics it has already one, i am in 2.78a i cant use principled there

Comment: You can't get away with just baking a single texture. You have to bake diffuse (albedo for the kids), normal, specular/metallic and use the Principled BSDF shader to create a material.

Comment: @metaphor_set i mean that the previewed texture in the 1st screenshot i want to bake it in the way that appears in the viewport, without lights and shadows, that one its the roughness map, i am using metalness,difuse, and bump map do you get it?

Comment: About your problem - there are tons of good tutorials on youtube that explain the process of baking PBR materials in detail.

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid please don't mark the question as solved or done. Instead of writing the solution as part of the question, write a proper answer in the answers section and mark it as accepted. Read: [Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally could bake this i just had to bake it with a diffuse shader which means i had to put my node setup in the color input of the diffuse node and then add other separate image with a new image created and just keep it selected and without plugging it in another node and then go to the bake settings, select diffuse, and uncheck direct and indirect button and then bake and wait until the bake was done.